# bootstrap progressbar thickness over 40px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar, css-animations

I want to use the progress bar of bootstrap as fancy looking barricade tape. That works quite nice, I also want want I to make the bar thicker. So I changed the background-size of the active progress-bar from 40px to 60:

```
div.progress.active .progress-bar {
    background-size: 60px 60px;
}
```

That worked so far that the bar is now thicker but the animation does not loop correctly anymore.

What do I have to change so the loop occurs after 60 instead of 40 pixel?

see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ok94vqoa/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to update the keyframes for the `progress-bar-stripes` animation to 60px as well.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/mkkpcvL8/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 60px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 60px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 60px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```